# Converting Cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column(columnName), 'varbinary(max)') back to nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql

I have a column on a table that is a varbinary(max), my problem is that I have been using `Cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("MyColumn"))', 'varbinary(max)')` to put file content into this column and now when I try to convert it back to nvarchar(max) the file content is corrupted, is there anyway of un-converting this data back to its original value?

I have tried to cast it back to nvarchar(max), I have tried to convert it to nvarchar(max), I have tried `Cast('' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("MyColumn"))', 'nvarchar(max)')`

But each time I try to create the file again it is corrupted